Complications while trying to withdraw my XLM from trustwallet
Tried moving some XLM from Trustwallet to another wallet but couldn't. After all due process, when I try to move assets this is the notification I get "tx_bad_auth []"
GBEVF4QRCNNUELPEMYSK6VDG3H32UXF5Q6UQXVC4WSHCLR4UHIE22CBE
Above is the wallet address.

tx_bad_auth indicates that signatures are missing or you're signing with wrong keys.
You have a multisig account that requires transactions to be also signed by whoever has the private keys to:

GCZBH2EQ7CVNVQAYNMGFIV6H4RSGMIBUYQFQMLA6LSNE5W7X52I6MXRK

